k6 Studio 0.6.0 not launching
K6 Studio not running after installation
freshly installed k6 Studio on Windows 10.
i have made sure that dot net framework 4.5 exists.
the installation seems like is done as I see the k6 Studio in start menu
however, after running the k6, the k6 Studio UI never launches.
i have tried running it from the start menu as well as from the installation directory ~\AppData\Local\k6_studio.exe
I see a bunch of processes in task manager but the k6 studio UI never launches
k6 Studio version
0.60
OS
windows 10
Steps to reproduce the problem
Freshly installed k6 Studio on Windows 10.
i have made sure that dotnet framework 4.5 exists.
the installation seems like is done as I see the k6 Studio in startmenu
however, after running the k6, the k6 Studio UI never launches.
i have tried running it from the startmentu as well as from the installation directory ~\AppData\Local\k6_studio.exe
i see a bunch of processes in task manager but the k6 studio UI never launches
Expected behaviour
expected to see the k6 Studio UI
Actual behaviour
k6 studio UI never comes up

there seems to be some issues between electron and some GPUs, as odd as it sounds have you tried updating your GPU drivers or reinstalling them ?
A similar issue was opened in github and you might find more information about it: https://github.com/grafana/k6-studio/issues/345
